# Non-alternating margins in book class

Tags: margins, geometry, books

For a `book` class, I specify margins like this:

```
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.5in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
```

But `left` and `right` appear to behave as `inner` and `outer`. I need to have the left margin 1.5 inch, and not have it alternate from page to page.

It looks like the `assymetric` option should do this, but it does not appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with the following technique:

First, `\usepackage{layout}` in the preamble and then `\layout` in the body to see what was happening.

Then,

```
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in,
            left=1.5in, right=1.25in, twosided]{geometry}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{36pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{36pt}
```

For `book` class, this ignores alternating pages (all pages are identical), and all margins are 1.25 in, except the left which is 1.5 in.

Comment: Interesting. I think it is more like a bug than a feature (is it?), I guess the `layout` package does not handle twosided documents properly. You shouldn't rely on bugs because they are not backward compatible in most cases. :) If you have a lot of these bug hacks you may have some problems when you update your packages.

Comment: The `layout` appears to handle twosided. One `\layout` command produced two pages (I assume because it knew L and R would be different) and the diagram was different on each of those pages.

Comment: What's wrong with setting `bindingcorrection`?

Comment: You mean the `bindingoffset` in your original answer? Not sure. It did not have the desired effect on my system.

Answer (score 10):

When in `twoside` mode, `geometry` uses `left` as `inner` and `right` as `outer`. You can use `bindingoffset` for this:

```
\usepackage[
  top=1.25in,
  bottom=1.25in,
  left=1.25in,
  right=1.25in,
  bindingoffset=0.25in,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
```

With the last option you get an integer number of lines for the text height, the rounding is as small as possible, usually unnoticeable.

This wouldn't be my preferred page setup, to be honest.

Comment: It isn't my preferred setup. Thesis requirements...

Comment: I like the simplicity of this configuration. Now I am interested: What do you suggest or what is your preferred page setup?

Comment: @Zelphir It depends on the document; this is definitely too symmetric, in a two side context.

Comment: @egreg lets say for a book of language exercises. What else would you change on the left or right side compare to the other?

Comment: @Zelphir That's too generic. The decision depend on too many factors to take care of. You may try looking at the `suftesi` class that defines several page formats.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just change from `twoside` to `oneside`? The following example works for me just fine.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1cm, bindingoffset=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum} % serving demonstration purposes only

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

The default value is `twoside`, and when you have a twosided document `left` and `right` margin specification will transform into `inner` and `outer`.

You should change the margin values of course.

Comment: The solution lies here folks!

Comment: one side has other effects - for example chapters no longer start on a facing page.