# Addmargin on even and odd pages

Tags: margins, double-sided

I have large outer margins and I want some time more text, on the left for even pages and on the right for odd pages. I tried:

```
\begin{addmargin*}
...
\end{addmargin*}
```

But the result is good only on the first page.
Can anyone help me?

Here is my MWE (after trying to implement solutions in Dennis's answer):

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[inner=1.5 cm,outer=5.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
%\usepackage{scrextend} % load it if you're not using a KOMA class 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{One} 
\lipsum[1-6] 
\section{One-one} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{15.5pt} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{15.5pt} 
\lipsum[2-11] 
\lipsum[1-12] 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt} 
\section{One-two} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try using the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package? Which document class you are using?

Comment: KOMA Script includes its own package for adjust the layout, it is `typearea` and I suggest to use it instead of `geometry`. Take a look at the documentation.

Comment: The `addmargin*` environment has one mandatory (and one optional) argument, what I miss in your example before the MWE. It is in my eyes thought for short margin changes. And note, what can be read in KOMA-Script documentation: “Whether a page is going to be on the left or right side of the book can not be determined for certain in the first LATEX run.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all problems are now solved (also with the header) with this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.5cm,paperheight=23cm, inner=1.5cm,outer=5.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newenvironment{TwoCol}{\small\begin{adjmulticols}{2}{0cm}{-4cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}
\newenvironment{OneCol}{\small\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-4cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}
\makeindex

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[LE]{4cm}%
    \fancyhfoffset[RO]{4cm}%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pseudosfera.png}}
\section{One-one}
\begin{OneCol}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{OneCol}
\marginpar{\textcolor{cyan}{Mauris ut leo. Cras
viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc.}}\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pseudosfera.png}}
\section{One-two}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{TwoCol}
\lipsum[2-12]
\end{TwoCol}

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

I show some page of output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks good! Glad you were able to find a fix. If you think that this answers your question, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon MMA's suggestion, you could probably fix the issue by using the geometry package with the option outermargin=n units for whatever value of n and unit you want. Although, you might want to check out [this question on alternating margins in the book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137021/17835) if you're having problems implementing the geometry solution.

If for whatever reason you don't want to use geometry, then [vmargin](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/vmargin) might be a barebones option for you.

You can find a whole host of options by consulting the [LaTeX wikibook section on page layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Margins), specifically the margin section of that article.

UPDATE:

I'm still not 100% sure what you're looking for, but here are two attempts using `geometry`.

2 inch outer margins (right for odd pages, left for even):

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[outermargin=2 in]{geometry}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{One} 
\lipsum[1-6] 
\section{One-one} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\lipsum[2-11] 
\lipsum[1-12] 
\section{One-two} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\end{document}
```

A somewhat absurd example to show changing margins on specific pages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[outermargin=2 in]{geometry}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{One} 
\lipsum[1-6] 
\section{One-one}
\newgeometry{outermargin= 5 in} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\lipsum[2-11] 
\restoregeometry 
\lipsum[1-12] 
\section{One-two} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\end{document}
```

Here we use `\newgeometry` to override what was set in the preamble (in this case, 2 inch outer margins) and specify a new option (in this case, the somewhat absurd 5 inch margins). `\restoregeometry` allows you to revert back to what was set in the preamble.

Both of these solutions, however, do alter the placement of the header/footer as you noted in comments.

UPDATE 2:

Here is an option using the `changepage` package that doesn't change the placement of headers and footers:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{changepage} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{One} 
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{1in}  % <----                  
Dummy text to test. \lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth} 
\pagebreak 
\section{One-one}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1in}{}                  
Dummy text to test. \lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth} 
\end{document}
```

This option allow you to manually set the width of a block of text. Doing this allows you to adjust the width of the text included in the `adjustwidth` environment. So long as the environment stays on a single page, it gets the desired result (I think). But obviously a somewhat of a pain of a solution.

Comment: Your answer alter also the setting of header and/or fouter.

Comment: Which one? Also, could you post [a Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that I can test my proposed solutions rather than guess at how your .tex file is set.

Comment: \documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=1.5 cm,outer=5.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{scrextend} % load it if you're not using a KOMA class

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{One-one}
\lipsum[1-3]
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{15.5pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{15.5pt}
\lipsum[2-11]
\lipsum[1-12]

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\section{One-two}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I edited my answer based on what you gave me. This seems to work for me, let me know if it isn't what you wanted.

Comment: In fact isn't what I want; the margin changes not when I want; your's instruction in the preambule for me means a change for the whole document; I dont undestand wy only at centain points, we have a change...

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Wow, yea, I completely misunderstood your request. I've removed my suggestion since it was completely off-base. If I understand correctly, you want to add to the outer margins so that there is more room for text. I'll take another crack at it.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Do you want larger outer margins on every page? Or only some pages?

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Ok, added two more attempts using geometry. Let me know whether these are what you're after. Still looking for a way to hold header/footer fixed. Once we have a solution we should go through and delete our comments in this thread--- it's getting rather long.

Comment: Sorry for my English! I want for normal text pages with 1.5 cm of inner margin, 5.5 cm of outer margin. Normally in outer margin I put figure, comments,... But, for example for historical notes or proposed problems, I want more space for text for half page, one page or more continuous pages. For this I need to work on outer margins and leave always the inner margin to 1.5 cm. The proposed solutions only works on one page!

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Yes, the most recently proposed solution will only work if the text within the environment stays on a single page. You could add this to every page, but that would obviously be very annoying and wouldn't allow you to do much editing after the fact. I'm not sure at this time how to fix that. I asked a question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151414/indicating-that-the-adjustwidth-environment-should-be-placed-around-text) along these lines. If I can get an answer to that question, then I think we'll have a decent solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found incompatibility with the `fancyhdr` package. So I dont use it. Making inspiration from this post [Problem with odd/even margins when environment crosses page boundaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50540/problem-with-odd-even-margins-when-environment-crosses-page-boundaries?rq=1) answer, my solution is:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.5cm,
            paperheight=23cm,
            inner=1.5cm,
            outer=5.5cm,
            top=3cm,
            bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{TwoCol}{\small\begin{adjmulticols}{2}{0cm}{-4cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}

\newenvironment{OneCol}{\small\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-4cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1]

\section{One-one}

\begin{OneCol}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{OneCol}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section{One-two}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{TwoCol}
\lipsum[2-12]
\end{TwoCol}


\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

And here is a part of the result (picture and side note added):
[image]

[image]

Comment: To override incopatibility with fancyhdr, the better could be to put running heads on the center and the page numbers in center footers.