# Larger left margin on one page. Larger right margin on the other page

Tags: margins, layout

How can I set the margin in such a way that one page has a larger margin on the left side and the other one a larger margin on the right side?

[image]

Update: I'm using the `article` document class.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: most classes have a `twoside` option to do that

Comment: @Mico article class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you load the `article` document class with the option `twoside`.

[image]

Please see section 3 of the user guide of the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for more information about setting page margins. In particular, if you use the `geometry` package to set the page parameter, you should use the parameters `inner` and `outer`, rather than `left` and `right`, when the `twoside` document class is in effect.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage[showframe,marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a line code like this:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.5cm,paperheight=23cm, inner=1.5cm,outer=5.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Unless one also specifies the option `twoside` -- either as an argument of the `\documentclass` instruction or as an option when loading the `geometry` package -- the instruction shown above will not let the OP achieve their formatting objective. Instead, it'll create the same (highly asymmetrical!) layout on every single page, regardless of whether the page is even- or odd-numbered.

Comment: @Mico I know and I forgot this aspect. But You can follow this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151533/24644 where I done (2013) a more complete answer on different aspects for bigger outer margin of twosided book: marginpar, headers, ...