# Multiple Images in outer border

Tags: figure-placement

I am trying to achieve what is in the image below

[image].

I considered to use wrapfig package, but I'd have to know beforehand where to place each wrapfig block.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[vcentering, dvips, top=1.8cm, bottom=1.8cm, inner=2.5cm, outer=1cm, papersize={14cm,23cm}]{geometry}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.25\linewidth}%
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\rule{2.5cm}{4cm}
\caption{caption}
\end{wrapfigure}%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.

Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.


Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.

Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.

Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.

Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.

Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.

Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

\end{document}
```

Is there any elegant way of achieving this, preferable with a single wrapfigure?

Comment: Use the tufte class

Comment: they look more like marginpar than wrapfig

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes! I cited mine solution for my problem more than 10 years ago.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the images and the text when it comes to vertical placement on the page? It doesn't seem that way in the images you show. So, technically, just a bunch of images in the "outer margin" and text in the "inner margin".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I dont think this is possible with wrapfig: it is very difficult to find one exact relationship between each picture on the margin and the text (@Werner). No need for this with marginpar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this old question/answer of mine: [Addmargin on even and odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151344/addmargin-on-even-and-odd-pages/151533#151533). Here I have a large margin where to put margin notes and or  pictures. The layout is flexible so you can have narrow margins also and back larger ones as you like. Grosso modo is the layout of my book on Relativity. You need to study carefully the code and You can have all You need.

**ADD**: I can add one output with more side picture and/or margin notes (two pages over 14).

[image]

I add also my code (to test it change the name of mine pictures with the name of your's pictures):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17.5cm,paperheight=23cm, inner=1.5cm,outer=5.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newenvironment{TwoCol}{\small\begin{adjmulticols}{2}{0cm}{-4cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}
\newenvironment{OneCol}{\small\begin{adjmulticols}{1}{0cm}{-4cm}}{\end{adjmulticols}}
\makeindex

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[LE]{4cm}%
\fancyhfoffset[RO]{4cm}%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{One}
    \lipsum[1]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logoRs}}
    \section{One-one}
    \begin{OneCol}
        \lipsum[1-4]
    \end{OneCol}
    
    \marginpar{\vspace{.5cm}\textcolor{cyan}{Mauris ut leo. Cras
            viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
            fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
            placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
            ac, nunc.}}\lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[7]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{grafico case}}
    
    \lipsum[1]\marginpar{\vspace{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logoRS}}
    
    \lipsum[3][1-4]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{ftrigo_s_c}}
    
    \section{One-two}
    \lipsum[1]
    \marginpar{\vspace{-2cm}\textcolor{cyan}{Mauris ut leo. Cras
            viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
            fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
            placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
            ac, nunc.}}\lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[5]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{aree e integrali}}
    \begin{TwoCol}
        \lipsum[2-12]
    \end{TwoCol}
    
    \lipsum[3-4]
    
    \chapter{Two}
    \lipsum[1]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logoRs}}
    \section{Two-one}
    \begin{OneCol}
        \lipsum[1-4]
    \end{OneCol}
    
    \marginpar{\vspace{.5cm}\textcolor{cyan}{Mauris ut leo. Cras
            viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
            fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
            placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
            ac, nunc.}}\lipsum[1]
    
    \lipsum[7]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{grafico case}}
    
    \lipsum[1]\marginpar{\vspace{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logoRS}}
    
    \lipsum[3][1-4]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{ftrigo_s_c}}
    
    \section{Two-two}
    \lipsum[1]
    \marginpar{\vspace{-2cm}\textcolor{cyan}{Mauris ut leo. Cras
            viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
            fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
            placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
            ac, nunc.}}\lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[5]\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{aree e integrali}}

 \end{document}
```

**Note**:  In the points of inserction of my pictures or notes sometime I added \vspace{-1cm},\vspsce{+0.5cm} or similar to better
fix the vertical position in the border.

With my code You can have:

```
 1. One large column without large border.
 2. One narrowed column with large border for pictures and or notes.
 3. Two columns without large border.
```

Short documents with `wrapfig`. I add an example with 2 pages:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{This is the image.}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is the image.}    
        \vspace{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{This is the image.}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{This is the image.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \textbf{Bold text bold text}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \lipsum[1][1-14]

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{This is the image.}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is the image.}    
        \vspace{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{This is the image.}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{This is the image.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \textbf{Bold text bold text}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    \lipsum[7][1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Curious about Grosso modo, is there a link you can share?

Comment: @yannisl I added the layout code.

Comment: Thanks, excellent layout, very attractive.

Comment: @user131051 You cant use wrapfig for long document because you need a strict relation between related text and wrapped figure. This is possible only for short documents and a lot of work to have the appropriate text and sided pictures. I add an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It does look like what I am looking for. However, my actual document is a behemoth with several layers of complexity that stumble upon everything (it uses A LOT of edefs and even DATABASES). My first attempt to use this in the actual document failed miserably. I might try later in the future but for the time being I'm just switching to a simpler layout. Thanks!